# I obtain "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server" in running docker container url localhost:8081 why?

Tags: php, windows, docker

[I do a

```sh
$ docker-compose up
```

in a containerized app
the app is running ok in docker but when i go to the url *localhost:8081*
i have this message of permissions
i don´t understand why, because i docker don´t show me an error.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdFmK.png)

Comment: Welcome. This is not nearly enough information for anyone to help you out...

Comment: thanks, ok i modify the body of the question, i´m nearby in docker

Comment: Please share more information with us. It would be helpful to provide the ```docker.compose.yml``` and tell us what you tried to achieve.  We do not know what you did or tried.

Comment: ok, i add an image with the docker-compose.yml